# routerlink between child components in angular 4

Tags: angular, routes, parent-child

I have a sidebar which has a dropdown Quiz->question. In the 'question' page(question page has path: /quiz/question) I've title, which on clicking should link to another component 'answerComponent'.

I tried to add children 'answer' to the 'question'.

```
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'question',
            component: viewComponent,
            children: [
              {
                path: 'answer',
                component: answerComponent,
              },
            ]
          },
        ]
  }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
   {
    path: 'quiz',
    loadChildren: './quiz/quiz.module#QuizModule'
  },
```

I would like to have a path something similar to this /quiz/question/answer. I added a routerlink in the questions page

```
<a [routerLink]="['answer']" [queryParams]= "{id: '2'}">click here</a>
```

I can see the url changing when I click to /quiz/question/answer?id=2
but I don't the see the answerComponent.html.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `answerComponent` is inside the `viewComponent` therefor you shall need a nested `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the `viewComponent`

**Edit** based on comments:

then your `answerComponent` should have another route at the same level of the `viewComponent` as:

```
children: [
      {
        path: 'question',
        component: viewComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'answer',
        component: answerComponent,
      },
    ]
```

Comment: when I add <router-outlet></router-outlet> in viewComponent, I'm seeing both view html and answer html when clicked on link

Comment: i'm not understanding what exactly you want to see after you click the link ?

Comment: I want to see only answer html after I click the link

Comment: If I have another route like you said, I'm getting this Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '/quiz/question/answer'

Comment: Try providing the full url with a slash at the beginning to the routerlink like ` "/quiz/answer"`

Comment: still getting the Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: /quiz/answer

Comment: What router link are you using to access the viewComponent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170180/discussion-between-modar-na-and-yer).

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it led me to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a queryParam and need to used it you should try something like:

```
  children: [
              {
                path: 'answer/:id',
                component: answerComponent,
              },
            ]
```

Comment: yes. thanks. but it not loading html. I can see only the url is changing